# How to import multiple WSDL's in WSo2 registry

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

From WSo2 registry login page we can upload 1 wsdl at a time and later can create dependency between the loaded ones. Now in my scenario i have around 400 WSDL with dependencies which are captured in excel sheet. Now is there any possibility to load the same into the register governance of WSO2?

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of WSDL collection, the best option is to, zip all the WSDL files and upload to the WSO2 Governance Registry.

Comment: I have tried this option, but when i uploaded all my SOA WSDL's most of them are abstract, but not the concrete. I can get the concrete WSDL's from the EM console, but how to upload all at a time to WSO2 registry